Not able to add Images and videos using quill rich text editor from local machine
Not able to Add Images and videos using Quill.js rich text editor.
I have added quill editor in my django blog site,everything works fine but when i try
to click image icon to add the image's from local machine i get this box.

i'm not able to select images from my local machine to upload in my blog using quill,
but when i try to paste url link of the image from the internet then it works perfectly but not from local machine.
this is my code :-
 const ColorClass = Quill.import("attributors/class/color");
  const SizeStyle = Quill.import("attributors/style/size");
  Quill.register(ColorClass, true);
  Quill.register(SizeStyle, true);

  //  #stop 
  const toolbarOptions = [
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"], // toggled buttons
    ["blockquote", "code-block"],
    ["link", "image", "video", "formula"],

    [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }], // custom button values
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }, { list: "check" }],
    [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }], // superscript/subscript
    [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }], // outdent/indent
    [{ direction: "rtl" }], // text direction

    [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }], // custom dropdown
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ font: [] }],
    [{ align: [] }],

    ["clean"], // remove formatting button
  ];



  document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = '';
  
  // Text editor
  const quill = new Quill("#textarea", {
    placeholder: "Compose an epic...",
    theme: "snow",
    syntax: {
      highlight: true, // Enable syntax highlighting
      detectLang: false  // Disable language detection
    },
    modules: {
          syntax:true,
      toolbar: toolbarOptions,
    },
  
  });

 



this is what i want, please look at the image:-

and yes even i'm not able to resize the image that i upload using URL.
please help.

You probably need to add your custom logic for uploading an image/video first. Otherwise you could only rely on embedding the image as data url, but that is not a good idea—especially not with videos.
